# I'm using wp_nav_menu to display my menu, but I want one more link in there that is a hardcoded link. How can I do this?

Tags: menus

I want to have all my dynamically generated links in my nav menu, but the second last one should be a link to my "Work" for my portfolio, which is just a link to a section on my main page. (Anchor link)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Using the Menus manager in WordPress you can add custom links. Make sure under Screen Options that Custom Links is checked.

[image]